# Memory spike/leak after QR Scannig

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, avfoundation

I'm working on an app in Swift and I noticed a huge memory jump after the custom ViewController that captures QR codes that I put together is presented.

The code is essentially based on this example: http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/ Before presenting the ViewController, the app's memory footprint according to Xcode is approx 17MB. after its presented, the memory spikes around 160-170MB and maintains that level even after it's dismissed. What I should be doing to reclaim that memory?

Comment: did the memory rise occur as soon as u present the camera view or after you read the qr code data ?

Comment: I'd suggest [downloading their final project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2857188/QRCodeReader.zip) and seeing if this memory behavior is manifested in their app. That will help determine whether the problem is in their code or yours. That will help narrow down the problem. In terms of fixing this problem, I'd suggest watching the dated, yet still relevant, WWDC 2013 video [Fixing Memory Problems](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/410/) which teaches you the types of memory problems that can exist and shows you how to use Instruments to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the problem. The memory spike was caused by an UIImage that I was using as an overlay that I had in that view controller. It was a pretty simple graphic and I never checked the file size - put it turns out it was a large pdf.